# Change game without changing the games added before

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im consuming a json file with the some games.
I want to add a new Game and the chooseGameToAdd() choose what game will be without changing the games added before

[image]
[image]

Json file:

[image]

Code:

```
import { games as gamesJson } from './games.json';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [whichGameIsVar, setWhichGameIsVar] = useState(0);
  const [state, setState]: any = useState([]);
  let game = gamesJson[whichGameIsVar].game;

  function addGame() {
    setState([...state, game]);
  }

  function chooseGameToAdd() {
    setWhichGameIsVar(whichGameIsVar + 1);
  }

  const GamesParent = (props: any) => {
    return (
      <div color={game}>
        <div>{game}</div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {state.map((item: any) => (
        <GamesParent key={item.id}>{item}</GamesParent>
      ))}
      <button onClick={addGame}>Add a Game</button>
      <button onClick={chooseGameToAdd}>Choose Game To Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Don't mutate state with `state.push([game])`.  Instead, `setState([...state, game])`

Comment: I edited, thank you Wyck!

Comment: It's not clear what your desired behaviour is. Could you please add some clarification to the question?

Comment: I want to add a new Game and the changeGame choose what game will be without changing the games added before(i will edit changeGame to chooseGameToAdd for clarification)

Comment: Why bother with typescript, and then use any everywhere? Just call it Javascript and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you do not have an id in the JSON objects, but you use item.id as the key. If you were actually using typescript and not just javascript with `any` everywhere, you would probably have picked that up. Either add the id to the JSON, or use the index as they key (less good!).

Answer (score 1):

You should put this outside `App` component

```
  const GamesParent = (props: any) => {
    return (
      <div color={game}>
        <div>{game}</div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

[check codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-test-2-kp8zb)